# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=R-ry^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on a problem for my optics class regarding electron-hole recombination in a semiconductor under strong injection. Assuming I haven't done anything wrong, I've arrived at the following equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=R-ry^2$$

where $R$ and $r$ are different variables and $y$ stands in for the change in carriers, a function of $t$.

The problem asks for an analytical solution to this equation, but I'm incredibly rusty with diff eqs. Does this have an analytical solution? I don't readily see how it could be separable or anything else.

I've looked for similar forms on a few websites, but none of them seem applicable. For example, here (http://web.uvic.ca/~kumara/econ501/schap22.pdf), on page 15, it provides a solution for (nonautonomous, separable) equations of the form

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y,t),$$

but even though the right side is a function of $y$ and $t$ (constant with $t$), I can't seem to separate it. So, I'm thinking that isn't right.

I think arriving at this equation might belong on a different forum (physics or somewhere), but I'm more interested in the math for this.

Would anyone happen to know if this even has an analytical solution? If so, how does one arrive there? The problem is trying to prove a power-law behavior instead of exponential behavior, if that gives any hint.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do we know anything about the signs of $r$ and $R$?

Answer (score 2):

The equation $$dy/dt = R - ry^2$$ is separable.

Note that you have $$\frac {dy}{R-ry^2} = dt$$ thus you need to integrate both sides and solve for $y$

$$\int \frac {dy}{R-ry^2}dy = t+C$$